# While setting option minLength 3 in autocomplete jquery it is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have three text input while setting minLength to 1 or 0 in jquery autocomplete it showing fine but when i will set minLenght to 2 or 3 it will not populating autocomplet select drop down. If I set any of one text-input minLength 1 or 0 in autocomplete thn it is working fine in that case thn after it will also showing autocomplete in other two text-input as well

Answer (score 1):

Show what you have tried so far.
It seems to be working here with 3 textbox and `minLength` property-

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags1" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      minLength:3
    });
   $( "#tags2" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      minLength:3
    });
   $( "#tags3" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      minLength:3
    });
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags 1: </label>
  <input id="tags1">
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags 2: </label>
  <input id="tags2">
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags 3: </label>
  <input id="tags3">
</div>
```

Comment: I am using jquery 1.8.16.custom.min.js in that case i'm not able to load autocomplete drop-down defining minLength:3 if i put any of having minLength:1 and try to search for that option thn all others inputbox working fine with minLength 
see my code at http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14222924